# LINQ条件分岐

Tags: c#, linq

**質問内容**
射影？について理解できなかったのでお聞きしたく質問させていただきます
linqの内部でif文のような動きは可能なのでしょうか？
**実現したい動作**
値が1000以上なら"●"
1000未満なら"空文字"
閲覧サイト
https://www.buildinsider.net/web/bookaspmvc5/050304

Comment: 上記リンクの射影に関する話は「select句を利用することで、範囲変数（エンティティ）から特定のプロパティだけを取り出したり」のくだりだけなので、今回の質問とは関係ないですね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

参照先記事では、`Released = (a.Released ? " 公開中 " : " 公開予定 ")`の部分が質問の内容に相当します。

この行では`a.Released`が`Boolean`なので、単に三項演算子の条件に入れていますが、この部分を`項目値 >= 1000`にすれば良い訳です。

`結果値 = (項目値 >= 1000 ? "●" : "")`といった感じになるでしょう。